# AngularJS Data from a Service

Tags: angularjs, service, angularjs-scope

So I have created a Notifications service in AngularJS and well I'm not getting any meaning full data back in my `$scope.Notifications` variable.

I can see the service is being called and running at the correct interval, and the correct data is being returned from the API:

`[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"content":"You have new mail: Test","read":null,"type":"mail","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38","updated_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"content":"You have new mail: Test","read":null,"type":"mail","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38","updated_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38"},{"id":3,"user_id":1,"content":"You have new mail: Test","read":null,"type":"mail","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38","updated_at":"2015-06-23 20:16:38"}]`

Essentially, all I need from this is a simple array of the users notifications.

Here is my service:

```
app.services.Notifications = ['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout){

    var timeoutId;
    var notificationService = this;

    function checkForNotifications(){
      console.log('checking')
      return $http.get('/api/notifications')
        .then(function(res){
              return res.data.filter(function(notification){
                  return notification.unread === true;
              })
        })
        .then(function(unreadNotifications){
          //fake for effect
          notificationService.count = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
          //notificationService.count = unreadNotifications.length;
        })
        .then(waitAndCheck)
    }

    function waitAndCheck(){
      return $timeout(function(){
        checkForNotifications()
      },5000);
    }

    return {
        Notifications: waitAndCheck()
    }
}];
```

And my controller:

```
app.controllers.notificationsController = ['$scope', 'Notifications', function($scope, Notifications) {
    $scope.Notifications = Notifications;
}];
```

If I console log $scope.Notifications in the controller I being return this:

```
Object {Notifications: d}Notifications: d$$state: Objectstatus: 1value: undefined__proto__: Object$$timeoutId: 1__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Your "service" returns an object with the key ``Notifications``

Answer (score 2):

Set your $scope.Notifications = Notifications.Notifications;

```
app.controllers.notificationsController = ['$scope', 'Notifications', function($scope, Notifications) {
    $scope.Notifications = Notifications.Notifications;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the thing which you are getting in console is nothing but a promise object which is conceptually correct. If you want the data from it then you use resolve that promise chain using `.then` function on `Notification` service.

```
Notifications.Notifications.then(function(data){
   $scope.Notifications = data;
})
```

Comment: Tried that, and now I get the following error in my console: TypeError: Notifications.then is not a function

Comment: @SeriousJelly it would be `Notifications.Notifications.`

Comment: Tried that too, and now the console is showing $scope.Notifications as undefined and there is no output to my screen :(

Comment: @SeriousJelly seems like you json doesn't have `unread` value which is filtering noting `notification.unread === true` here

Comment: Ah, yea that makes sense, ermmmm, still if I show {{ Notifications }} in my view, I am getting nothing, Scope also shows as undefined at the first instance (when the app is loaded)

Comment: @SeriousJelly could you try by making correct json by adding value for unread..then the picture would be clear..currently no value is return from the service which makes $scope.Notifications `undefined`..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I removed that filter, it is now return $http.get('/api/notifications')
        .then(function(res){
              return res;
        })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81465/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-seriousjelly).